# How to change the angle of an edge in a cylinder

Tags: edges, normals

As you can see from this image, all of the edges in my model above have different angles (per Mesh Display > Edge Info > Angle). I'd like to adjust them all so that they all have the same angle.

Is there a way to manually set an edge angle? And if not, is there an easy work around to set all of these to the same angle?

[image]

I'm basically trying to get it back to having the same consistent angle from the base the whole way around the object, without recreating it from scratch.

Comment: This looks like a beformed (proportional edit) cylinder. Are you trying to recover the original cylinder?  Cylinder Meshes generated by Blender have equal length edges and angles on the two circular ends.  Are you trying to have the result be circular as in this letter (o) or an arc as in this letter (c) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

- The add-on LoopTools can change a non-circular loop to a circular loop.  Add ons need to be installed.  33 second task.  Search info here at BSE.

[image]

Example. LoopTools changes a beformed cylinder into a more regular frustrum. We need only to select in Edit Mode the Top and Bottom loops. Regular Cylinder is easy variation.

- You need to be able to specify one or more starting points in your mesh so the equal angle bend can begin.  This a design goal for you to state, not a difficult technical issue.  This is not quite so obvious in your image since the shape is a cylinder rather than a more common case of a plane.

[image]

- Armature with constraints can specify an angle, and circular arc.
- A subdivided curve with a Curve Constraint may be useful.
- Proportional Edit may be useful
- If you want manual labor, you change change the pivot center for rotation scaling to be the cursor and move the cursor to the current selection.